# Pass an identifier to jQuery click event handler

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have code that pulls records from a database and generates a table (via ajax). I want to put a button in each row of the table to do some processing on the specified record, but I need a way to know which record it applies to. I've tried something like this:

In the .ajax method that generates the table, I have code that builds up a string, and the subs it into the table body. This is the key line for this problem:

```
ActionTable += "<td><button class='btn' id='review' name = '" + obj[line].iID + "'>Review</button></td>";
```

In the document.Ready function, I've tried a number of variations along these lines:

```
    $('#review').on('click', function(){
        alert("In click");

        var actionID = $(this).attr("name");
        reviewAction(actionID);
    });
```

But it's become clear that inside this code $(this) no longer applies to the button that was clicked. I also tried setting up data in the on('click' code, something like this:

```
        $('#review').on('click', {actionID:$(this).attr("name")}, function(){
            alert("In click");

            reviewAction(actionID);
        });
```

But that didn't work either. I can't set up a separate handler for each button because I don't know until runtime how many rows there will be or what the IDs for each row will be.

So how do I create a handler for these buttons that knows which button called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler accepts the [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) object as argument, you can then use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to know what element has been clicked.

Note that if you have nested elements within your target with a registered handler, you might want to use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) (which, unless you used arrow functions, should be equivalent to `this`, really).

### Example 1

#### HTML

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-value="1">One</li>
  <li data-value="2">Two</li>
  <li data-value="3">Three</li>
</ul>
```

#### JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
  $('#list').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log( $(e.target).data('value') );
  });
});
```

<kbd>[**Working Example**](https://jsbin.com/legigiweba/3/edit?html,js,console,output)</kbd>

### Example 2

#### HTML

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-value="1">
    <span data-value="nested">One</span>
  </li>
  <li data-value="2">Two</li>
  <li data-value="3">Three</li>
</ul>
```

#### JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
  $('#list li').on('click', function(e) {
    // Click on li[data-value='1']
    console.log( $(e.target).data('value') ); // 'nested'
    console.log( $(e.currentTarget).data('value') ); // 1
  });
});
```

<kbd>[**Working Example**](https://jsbin.com/legigiweba/2/edit?html,js,console,output)</kbd>